# Match inclusive between start and end over multiple lines

Tags: regex

I have a large amount of Toml files, some of which contain a parameter I would like to remove. I'm having difficulty building a regex that matches the starting text `categories =` and ending text `]`. Per the sample below, my regex matches the text in between the start and end text, but does not include the start and end text itself. How do I modify the regex to capture everything between the start and end text?

My current regex is: `(?<=categories)(.*)(?=])`

The sample .toml contains:

```
+++
slug = "twenty-years-from-now-you-will-be-more"
description = ""
tags = [
  "Quoteoftheday",
  "Quote",
]
categories = [
  "Quoteoftheday",
  "Quote",
]
date = 2014-01-16T07:13:10-08:00
title = "twenty years from now..."
draft = false

+++
```

The text I want to capture with the regex is:

```
categories = [
  "Quoteoftheday",
  "Quote",
]
```

Sample code is [here.](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/741)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using negated character class you can make it work without `DOTALL` or `s` flag so that it can work with flavors where `DOTALL` isn't supported like Javascript.

```
\ncategories([^]]*)\]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/742)

---

To make it work with `sed` use this command:

```
sed -i.bak '/^categories[ \t]*=/,/\]/d' file

cat file

+++
slug = "twenty-years-from-now-you-will-be-more"
description = ""
tags = [
  "Quoteoftheday",
  "Quote",
]
date = 2014-01-16T07:13:10-08:00
title = "twenty years from now..."
draft = false

+++
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
(?s)categories[\s=\[]+(.*?)]
```

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` single line flag/modifier
- `categories[\s=\[]+` match 'categories' and any instances of space = [
- `(.*?)]` match any character and ]

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kQbVHi/3)**

Comment: This produces a good match, how would you construct a sed command to remove all instances of this match from a set of files in a directory?